# If $a_k$ is a sequence that converges to $1/2$, prove that $b_k = 1/(1-a_k)$ is Cauchy

Tags: cauchy-sequences

The question asks to prove directly from the definition of a Cauchy sequence that $b_k$ is Cauchy, but I am hopelessly confused, these are evidently series approaching infinity

Comment: First try to find out, why $b_k$ must tend to $2$, then apply the proof.

Comment: There are no series, just a sequence. It is clear that if $(a_k)$ converges to $1/2$, then $(b_k)$ converges also. So it is Cauchy. Your exercise is to prove that using the definition of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Yes but im struggling as to prove it using the definition, any advice with how to prove it using the definition would be appreciated

Comment: $b_k$ converges to $1/(1-1/2)=2$ and so it is Cauchy (every convergent sequence is Cauchy)

Comment: If a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N_\varepsilon$ such that $|x-x_n|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, Then, for all $n,m\geq N_\varepsilon$  $$|x_n-x_m|\leq|x_n-x|+|x-x_m|<\varepsilon/2 +\varepsilon.2=\varepsilon$$.

Comment: apologies i left off the fact that they told us to pretend we do not know that bk is convergent in the question

Answer (score 1):

This may seem as cheating. But: $f(x)=1/(1-x)$ is continuous everywhere except on $x=1$. Therefore since $a_k$ converges to $1/2$, $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}b_k=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{1-a_k}=\frac{1}{1-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k}=\frac{1}{1-1/2}=2.$$ The claim $b_k$ is Cauchy trivially follows from the fact that $b_k$ converges.

Yet, I'll call this as a rigorous proof since you can prove the continuity easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
To prove directly that $(b_k)$ is Cauchy, compute  first
$$b_k-b_\ell=\frac1{1-a_k}-\frac 1{1-a_\ell}=\frac{a_k-a_\ell} {(1-a_k)(1-a_\ell)}$$
and note that, since $(a_k)$ converges to $\dfrac12$, if $k,\ell$ are large enough, we have, say
$$1-a_k,\enspace1-a_\ell>\frac14.$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful

Comment: Actually after working on it, im still struggling to get the next steps

Comment: Use that $(a_k)$ is Cauchy, and you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $a_n\rightarrow\frac12$, there is $N$ such that $|a_n-1|>\frac{1}{3}$ for all $n\geq N.  (details left to you)

$\Big|\frac{1}{1-a_n}-\frac{1}{1-a_m}\Big|=\frac{|a_n-a_m|}{|1-a_n|\,|1-a_m|}\leq 9|a_n-b_m|$

As $a_n$ converges, $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy and so, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N_2\geq N$ such that $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon/9$ for all $n,m\geq N$.